# put_via_redirect in Rails Integration Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I have this route:

```
put "/users/:id/activate?:verification_key" => "users#activate", :as => 'verification'
```

I want to access this route in an integration test

```
put_via_redirect verification_path, :id => 1, :verification_key => 1234
```

Rake test gives:

```
No route matches {:action=>"activate", :controller=>"users"} missing required keys: [:id, :verification_key]
```

What is the correct syntax for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easer to change the parameter syntax and use a slash instead.

```
get "/users/:id/:verification_key" => "users#activate", :as => 'verification'
```

From the user-mailer template I access the link like this:

```
  <a href="<%=@url%><%=url_for verification_path(:host => @host, :id=>@user.id, :verification_key=>@key) %>">Activate</a>
```